# Cannot verify phone number with code in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, sms

I'm using firebase for phone number verification via sms.

This works nice when the verification is automatically done (SMS is sent and automatically app reads it and does the operations related to that the phone number has been verified).

But I'm now trying to make the verification with the code that is sent in this sms, as maybe not every user is going to be able to automatically read the sms message.

I thougt that the function PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber would be overloaded with some option that would allow to send that code and perform the verification, but unless I'm missing something there doesn't seem to be a way with it.

On the other hamd I know [this way of performing a verification via sent code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?hl=en-419), but it does require to sign in firebase, and I don't want that unless there's no another way, all that should happen is that the user sends its phone number along with the code and if correct, firebase sends something that is understood by the app as that the verification has been correct (no signing in anywhere).

Is there a way to do what I'm mentioning?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with my new app released in Google Play Store. I just don't receive de sms code.
I mention that when I tested the app in debug mode and release mode it worked perfectly fine. The problem occurs when I download the app from Play Store. 
Maybe you are right and the problem is that i didn't login user, because at this moment rules in Firebase Database are read and write == true.